# Eclipse 4 e4 - about dialog

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I am building an Eclipse 4 Application and I would like to make an about dialog as known from Eclipse 3.
I used the Menu Spy and learned the following:

The active contribution location URI:

```
menu:help?after=about
```

The active action definition identifier:

```
org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction
```

The active contribution item class:

```
ActionFactory$WorkbenchCommandAction
```

The contributing plug-in:

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench
```

**QUESTION:**
Can I somehow use this action to open or extend the about dialog in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such a thing like preimplemented "about" dialog in e4.
The old about dialog relied on the ´org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench´ which is null in new e4 applicaiton-model.

So the about dialog must be implemented from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

These components aren't migrated yet to eclipse 4. I created a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392715) for this issue. If you think this is important to be fixed, please consider a vote on this report.